# How to print at an architectural scale?

Tags: export, printing, scale, units, scale-bar

I'm a landscape architecture student who is starting to learn QGIS. How would I be able to manually input a scale I want in inches to feet when exporting for print? For example, if I would like to print 1" = 100' would I be able to do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to contain one One question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GIS, scale is usually expressed as a ratio. So you just need to work out the ratio of the scale you want. 1" = 100', for example, would be a scale (ratio) of 1:1200 (1 inch = 1200 inches), so if you set your scale in GIS to 1:1200, then your printed map will be at a scale of 1:1200. How you communicate that to the map reader is up to you, I don't believe QGIS has the ability to put a dynamic scale text element on a layout, but you can just add a text box that says 1" = 100'.

For the printed scale to be accurate, you will need to ensure that your printer is printing at 100% of actual size, and is not doing any automatic resizing to fit your paper size.